# Delete row in db

Tags: php

I have button, onclick I get link like that : //..../update_news.php?newsID=112&&value=delete

using this code:

```
'<td style="width:50px;"> <u> <b><a href="update_news.php?newsID='.$row['newsID'].'&&'.'value=delete'.'">'.'<img src="src/img/delete.png" /></b></u></td></a>';
```

Then i try to Delete a row using this class, but it doesnot work:

```
class Delete{
    private $db;
    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
        }
        public function Delete($title, $date, $short_description, $description){

        $newsID = $_Get['newsID'];
        $delete = $_Get['delete'];

        if(isset($delete))
        {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM `News` WHERE  newsID= :newsID";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':newsID', $_GET['newsID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "WORKS";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Papapapapa";
        }

}}
```

I call this class:

```
$object = new Delete();
$object->news($newsID, $title, $date, $short_description, $description);
```

Thank you if anyone will help me.

Comment: Note that you have 2 ampersands after the newsID value.

Comment: Your class does not have a method called `news()`.

Comment: Can you please show us what it does output? Also run the statement straight in your database management software

Comment: This is a bit of a lazy question: you should really describe what you mean by "does not work". and you should debug yourself a bit (echo what all the values are for instance) before asking us to do that for you, so you know where you go wrong. Having said that: Take a look at `$_Get` vs `$_GET`

Comment: this is some really bad OOP.

Comment: You might also want to check where you're defining `$pdo` in your function.

Comment: I am really starting, please dont jugde. Thanks all for help

Comment: The variable `$newsID` can be deleted, as you're not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are calling news() method? You wrote method into a constructor. You must wrote into a class like this:

```
class Delete{
    private $db;
    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function DeleteNews($title, $date, $short_description, $description){

        $newsID = $_Get['newsID'];
        $delete = $_Get['delete'];

        if(isset($delete))
        {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM `News` WHERE  newsID= :newsID";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':newsID', $_GET['newsID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "WORKS";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Papapapapa";
        }

    }
}
```

After than call the method DeleteNews.

```
$object = new Delete();
$object->DeleteNews($title, $date, $short_description, $description);
```

Comment: I happened to have stumbled onto this Q&A and noticed your answer contains `$_Get` instead of `$_GET`. `$_GET` is a superglobal and must be set in upper-case letters. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php - I see that is what the OP's question had, yet this should have been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the first thing you should do is rename your `Delete` function so it isn't capitalized, so you won't confuse it with your class.

The second thing I would try is actually calling the (soon to be renamed) `delete` function because right now you are calling a function called `news`, which is either a typo or code we can't see. Try `$object->delete(...)` instead of `$object->news(...)`.