# Using a form to allow user to delete record from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to echo a form through PHP so that the submit button value looks like a URL, which is does perfectly with this code. Next I am trying to get the WID value from a previous query with the variable `$resulting[WID]`.

I know this variable is capturing the value correctly. The problem I am having is that I can't seem to get the form below to pass this value to my PDO query so that the record will be deleted from the database if the user clicks on "Delete". Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

//Get WID from form

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
$the_WID = $_POST['WID'];
```

//The PDO query

```
$dlt = "DELETE FROM writing WHERE writing.WID = :writing.WID";

$stmtdlt = $dbh->prepare($dlt);
$stmtdlt->bindParam(':writing.WID', $the_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                           
$stmtdlt->execute(); 
}
```

//THE FORM (displayed so that it looks like a text link through PHP echo)

```
echo "<table class=\"edit\"><tr class=\"edit\"><td class=\"edit\"><FORM METHOD=\"POST\" 
style=\"display: inline\" ACTION=\"\" class=\"ten\">"; 
echo "<input TYPE=\"submit\" name=\"remove\" VALUE=\"Delete\">";
echo "<input TYPE=\"hidden\" name=\"remove\" VALUE=\"$resulting[WID]\">";  
echo "</FORM></td>";  
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: For one thing, both your submit and hidden form elements bear the same name. You're also not using `:stories.WID:` as a proper bind; which you can't bind columns in the first place.

Comment: Plus, your form tags aren't in the right place. `<form><table></table></form>` is the way it should be done.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Can you clarify about the :stories.WID binding issue? Do you mean it should just be :WID and leave the table name out? Not sure what you mean when you say I can't bind columns? I bind column field names all the time...

Comment: No, you can't bind columns (nor tables). You can however, use variables. This for instance is OK `$column="column_name";` then doing `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE $column='something'` - The thing is with binding, is that it doesn't know ahead of time what it's supposed to bind. This is a security feature with any prepared statements. If a potential hacker knew what to look for ahead of time, it would make it easier for them to do so (wink).

Comment: I just removed the name attribute from the submit input and fixed the form issue, although that isn't the real issue as you know. Is the problem perhaps that I am not capturing the event of the user clicking the submit button to trigger the variable to be passed to the query?

Comment: Hmmm. I've done it like this elsewhere (as instructed) and it works well, such as $results->bindParam(':writing.WID', $WID, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$results2->bindParam(':writing.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: just caught one thing...WID is in the writing table so I changed it from stories.WID to writing.WID. Can you share a snippet so I'm more clear about how the bind should work?

Comment: you're preparing it, dont substitute it with your variable, try `DELETE FROM writing(writing.WID
WHERE writing.WID = :stories.WID)`

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/ under DELETE. Base yourself on that and follow the same convention. Plus, this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/20547674/

Comment: Just updated post. I think I have the PDO correct now. But still nothing. Can it be that I need javascript to capture the click event to trigger the passing of the variable?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Funny, I did just that before I saw your comment. Updated my post so I think the PDO is perfect now. But still nothing.

Comment: Ok, it's time to take out the big gun now. Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything/errors.

Comment: Done. Yields no errors

Comment: Actually, I just tried to echo the_WID after clicking on the DELETE link. Once I click delete I get this error: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined